# Countifs and Distinct Values Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I am trying to count distinct site visits in a certain area in a certain month.  I am using an array as the data set is large.  I can count visits in each area in each month:

```
ARRAYFORMULA({"Visits";IF($A3:$A="","",countifs(Sheet1!$F:$F,A3:A,Sheet1!$H:$H,B3:B))})
```

But I don't know how to count *distinct* visits.

[DATA SET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vovxc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAP()` function to make it array formula and use `FILTER()` and `COUNTUNIQUE()`. Try-

```
=MAP(A3:A10,B3:B10,LAMBDA(x,y,COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER(G3:G,F3:F=x,H3:H=y))))
```

To refer full column as `MAP()` function input, use-

```
=MAP(A3:INDEX(A3:A,COUNTA(A3:A)),B3:INDEX(B3:B,COUNTA(A3:A)),LAMBDA(x,y,COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER(G3:G,F3:F=x,H3:H=y))))
```

If you do not have any empty cells from A3 to B column then we can simplify the formula using `TOCOL()`.

```
=MAP(TOCOL(A3:A,1),TOCOL(B3:B,1),LAMBDA(x,y,COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER(G3:G,F3:F=x,H3:H=y))))
```

> ***Edit:*** You can omit `FILTER()` by using `COUNTUNIQUEIFS()`.

```
=MAP(TOCOL(A3:A,1),TOCOL(B3:B,1),LAMBDA(x,y,COUNTUNIQUEIFS(G3:G,F3:F,x,H3:H,y)))
```

[image]